# Java: cannot find symbol when compiling

Tags: java, command-line, compiler-errors

So I'm completely new to running codes through command lines (I'm used to working with Eclipse). I can't figure out a solution for compiling classes when I use different packages.

This is my first class (GreetingsUniverse.java):

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial;
import com.ocajexam.tutorial.*;

public class GreetingsUniverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, Universe!");
        Earth e = new Earth();
    }
}
```

Second class (Earth.java):

```
package com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets;
public class Earth {
    public Earth() {
    System.out.println("Hello from Earth!");
    }
}
```

I tried compliling it as follows:

```
javac -d . Earth.java
```

Which creates an Earth class file in com/ocajexam/tutorial/planets.

Then, when I try:

```
javac -d . GreetingsUniverse.java
```

I get the following error messages:

```
GreetingsUniverse.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Earth e = new Earth();
                ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
GreetingsUniverse.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                Earth e = new Earth();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
2 errors
```

I also tried leaving out -d and other things but keep getting the same error. I think it has something to do with the different packages. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Use an IDE like Eclipse

Comment: Try using -classpath alternativley specify all files you want to compile instead of doing it separatley

Comment: Try `cd`-ing to the top of your package tree and running `javac com/ocajexam/tutorial/*.java` and `javac com/ocajexam/tutorial/planets/*.java`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Earth` is in the package `com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets` yet in your import in `GreetingsUniverse` you are importing `com.ocajexam.tutorial.*`, this won't import class `Earth`for you. So change `import com.ocajexam.tutorial.*;` either to `import com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets.*;` or `import com.ocajexam.tutorial.planets.Earth;`